# Matching two types of data (elevation and imagery) which are in different scale?

Tags: qgis, usgs, map-matching

My problem is that elevation and imagery data I'm getting from USGS is in different scales and is aligned to different grids. I don't want to match it manually in Photoshop.

Does QGIS know how to match this data?

(huge, blue square is elevation, small ones, imagery)

[image]

Answer (score 4):

As long as each dataset you are adding (elevation and imagery) has the correct grid information, QGIS will be able to project both datasets properly. If they cover the same area, than you will have the map-matching you are looking for.

Install QGIS, then add your datasets. That should work out as you are interested in.

Comment: yes, you are correct, QGIS did the job!  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6HFdltOGbbs